# Screen capture for TableView NOT only for visible cells but for all available cells

Tags: iphone

I want to take screen shot of my tableview for all the number of cells NOT only for visible cells. number of rows are dynamic.

If there are 30 Rows then I want all 30 rows in one screen shot. 
I have tried with using tableview's total height as

```
self.tblView.contentSize.height
```

with this code i m getting screen of all cells but Except visible cell all other part of screen is blank.

I am using below code to take screen shot

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view 
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenRect.size.height=self.tblView.contentSize.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

[view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this is more complex that just taking a screen shot because the cells are not drown.

Comment: @Alex Terente, Is there any alternate way to capture all cells?

Comment: You could just draw every thing in a CGContext and take the image from that context.

Answer (score 1):

"Screen Capture" is a screen capture. You cannot capture any content other than the one displayed. I don't see any solutions other than making several captures, each time programmatically scrolling the tableview by a table height, then merging the images.